# R data.table using "rollapply" on chunks of rows

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I was wondering if there is an equivalent of `rollapply` for `data.table`. For example if I have a data.table like the following

```
x = data.table(val1 = 1:10,val2 = 21:30)
```

I would like to apply a function that works on rows 1 to 3 (say), then 2 to 4, 3 to 5 and so on, while maintaining it as a data.table within the function. This is very similar to `rollapply` but for data.table. If I try `rollapply` I get an error as it is meant to operate on vectors only I think.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `rollapply(x, 3, sum)` works for me where `x` is as you defined it.  Also its not the case that `rollapply` is only meant to act on vectors.  Suggest you read `?rollapply` .